# WebDriver Selenium API: FirefoxDriver on linux?

Tags: linux, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

has anyone been successful in running tests using FirefoxDriver on a linux distro ? If so, which distro are you using ? Are you using xvfb ?

right now, I am thinking of simply using windows 2003 server, but it's a bit more expensive and I am more familiar with linux environment.

Comment: If you can do without xvfb and simply use the standard firefox browser you should be fine. I've run into different behavior when I try to setup selenium webdriver tests using xvfb. Though if you are running a headless machine then xvfb is one of your only choices.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu + Selenium-Webdriver + Firefox works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara + Selenium + Webdriver + Firefox works out-of-the-box. Using Archlinux here.

Comment: I dont find them on AUR

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 6 - firefox default distro & firefox updated version works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use ubuntu and it works fine for me. Check whether you are using the updated version of selenium server jar file, u can download it from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/download/)